# UNIX: Compare 2 files and append duplicates - almost working

Tags: unix, awk, comparison, grep, duplicates

I'm working on a Unix script where I have to compare 2 files. One file is a list of IDs (ids.txt and another is a list of the duplicate IDs(duplicate.txt). I need to compare both files and add a counting system to each duplicate found in ids.txt. I have already created the file of duplicates and the ID files, I just need to compare them and add numbers to the end of the duplicates. I've tried this so far:

```
awk 'FILENAME=="duplicates.txt" {arr[$0]++}
 FILENAME=="ids.txt" {print $0, arr[$0]} ' duplicates.txt ids.txt
```

This almost works, the only problem is that all of the duplicates have been appended with a 1 at the end, but I need it to count up on each duplicate. For example, if I have dabbot 3 times in the file, I need it to say dabbott1 dabbott2 dabbott3.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt the array used in the first scope (with filename = duplicates.txt) is the same of the other one (with filename = ids.txt); would you mind to post some sample of each file?

Comment: And also include expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809059/unix-compare-2-files-and-append-to-duplicates

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that question went largely unnoticed. Perhaps it could be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your script as a basis:

```
awk 'FILENAME=="duplicates.txt" {arr[$0]++}
     FILENAME=="ids.txt"        { if (arr[$0]) printf "%s%d\n", $0, ++cnt[$0];
                                  else print
                                }' \
     duplicates.txt ids.txt
```

You count/record the duplicates as they arrive so you know which lines are duplicates.  It doesn't matter much whether the duplicates files lists a duplicated name once or many times; both will be OK.

The second loop notes whether the current line is in the duplicates list; if so, it prints the line followed by a pre-incremented counter (so the first appearance of a given duplicate is printed with a 1 as the suffix); otherwise, the line is printed unchanged.

You can debate the merits of `FILENAME = "filename"` vs `FNR == NR` to distinguish between the two files; the net result is the same, so you could also try:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { arr[$0]++; next }
               { if (arr[$0]) printf "%s%d\n", $0, ++cnt[$0];
                 else print }' duplicates.txt ids.txt
```

Note that using `print` is not OK if you want `dabbot1` with no space between the `dabbot` and the `1`.  If the space doesn't matter and you always want a suffix (of 0 in case of no duplicate), you can just write `printf $0, ++cnt[$0]` instead of the `if` with `printf`.

If you use the `FNR == NR` trick, you don't even need to pre-prepare the duplicates file; you can simply use:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { arr[$0]++; next }
               { if (arr[$0] > 1) printf "%s%d\n", $0, ++cnt[$0];
                 else print }' ids.txt ids.txt
```

The first time through the file, it sorts out which records are duplicates by counting them.  The second time through the file, it knows which are duplicates (the count in `arr` is more than `1`) and can print the suffix on those lines.